# php can not get array value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, key, element

I have an array:

```
Array
(
[ZmlkPTQ3NyZ1aWQ9MTA4NDQmdXNlcl9sb2dpbj52
] => 
[format] => html
[Itemid] => 971
[option] => com_ira_financial_forms
[view] => add_self_directed_ira
)
```

And I would like to get the first value in the array:

```
ZmlkPTQ3NyZ1aWQ9MTA4NDQmdXNlcl9sb2dpbj52
```

I have tried each of the following:

- `array_values($_array)[0];`
- `$data[0];`
- `array_keys($data)[0];`

But none of them work, and I instead get an empty string. I need to get the first element or key of the array.

Comment: `array_key_first($_array)` [array_key_first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `array_key_first(your_array)`

Get the first key of the given array without affecting the internal array pointer.